# How to optimize this range query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a table with 15 million records containing name, email addresses and IPs. I need to update another column in the same table with the country code using the IP address. I downloaded a small database (ip2location lite - https://lite.ip2location.com/) containing the all ip ranges and associated countries. The ip2location table has the following structure;

```
CREATE TABLE `ip2location_db1` (
  `ip_from` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_to` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` char(2) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `idx_ip_from` (`ip_from`),
KEY `idx_ip_to` (`ip_to`),
KEY `idx_ip_from_to` (`ip_from`,`ip_to`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

I'm using the following function to retrieve the country code from an ip address;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `get_country_code`(
    ipAddress varchar(30)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(2)
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE ipNumber INT UNSIGNED;
        DECLARE countryCode varchar(2);
        SET ipNumber = SUBSTRING_INDEX(ipAddress, '.', 1) * 16777216;
        SET ipNumber = ipNumber + (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ipAddress, '.', 2 ),'.',-1) * 65536);
        SET ipNumber = ipNumber + (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ipAddress, '.', -2 ),'.',1) * 256);
        SET ipNumber = ipNumber + SUBSTRING_INDEX(ipAddress, '.', -1 );

        SET countryCode = 
            (SELECT     country_code 
            FROM        ip2location.ip2location_db1
            USE INDEX   (idx_ip_from_to)
            WHERE       ipNumber >= ip2location.ip2location_db1.ip_from AND ipNumber <= ip2location.ip2location_db1.ip_to
            LIMIT       1);

        RETURN countryCode;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I've ran an EXPLAIN statement and this is the output;

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'ip2location_db1', NULL, 'range', 'idx_ip_from_to', 'idx_ip_from_to', '5', NULL, '1', '33.33', 'Using index condition'
```

My problem is that the query on 1000 records takes ~15s to execute which mean running the same query on all the database would require more than 2 days to complete. Is there a way to improve this query.

PS - If I remove the USE INDEX (idx_ip_from_to) the query takes twice as long. Can you explain why?

Also I'm not a database expert so bear with me :)

Comment: Does the table have overlapping ranges?  If so, you can't optimize it (even with Gordon's suggestion).

Comment: Don't use `utf8` for `country_code` -- it takes 6 bytes when you need only 2; use `ascii`.

Comment: Normalize out `country_name`; it is cluttering up the table.

Comment: (I sent a comment about `country_code` to ip2location.com.)

Answer (score 0):

This can be quite tricky.  I think the issue is that only the `ip_from` part of the condition can be used.  See if this gets the performance you want:

```
    SET countryCode = 
        (SELECT     country_code 
         FROM        ip2location.ip2location_db1 l
         WHERE       ipNumber >= l.ip_from 
         ORDER BY ip_to
         LIMIT       1
        );
```

I know I'm leaving off the `ip_to`.  If this works, then you can do the full check in two parts.  First get the `ip_from` using a similar query.  Then use an equality query to get the rest of the information in the row.

Comment: Thanks... will try that now

Answer (score 0):

The reason `USE INDEX` helps is because MySQL wasn't planning to use that index.  Its optimizer chose a different one, but it guessed wrong.  Sometimes this happens.

Also, I'm not sure if this will affect performance a ton, but you should just use `INET_ATON` to change the IP address string into an integer.  You don't need that `SUBSTRING_INDEX` business, and it may be slower.

What I would do here is measure the maximum distance between from and to:

```
SELECT MAX(ip_from - ip_to) AS distance
FROM ip2location_db1;
```

Assuming this is not a silly number, you will then be able to use the ip_from index properly.  The check becomes:

```
WHERE ipNumber BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_from + distance
    AND ipNumber <= ip_to
```

The goal here is to make all of the information to find a narrow set of rows come from a limited range of one column's value: ip_from.  Then ip_to is just an accuracy check.

The reason you want to do this is because the ip_to value (second part of the index) can't be used until the corresponding ip_from value is found.  So it still has to scan most of the index records for low values of ip_from without an upper bound.

---

Otherwise, you might consider measuring how unique the IP addresses are in your 15 million records.  For example, if there are only 5 million unique IPs, it could be better to extract a unique list, map those to country codes, and then use that mapping (either at runtime, or to update the original table.)  Depends.

If the values are very unique, but potentially in localized clusters, you could try removing the irrelevant rows from ip2location_db1, or even horizontal partitioning to improve the range checks.  I'm not sure this would win anything, but if you can use some index on the original table to consult specific partitions only, you might be able to win some performance.